# How do I connect to a Server 2008 Core R2 that is not in the same domain from mmc/server manager

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-access, connection

I have set these rules on Server 2008 Core:

netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="File and Printer Sharing" new enable=yes 
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Remote Administration" new enable=yes
netsh advfirewall set currentprofile settings remotemanagement enable

Still wont be able to connect from another Server 2008?

Comment: remote admin via mmc and snapins and via Server Manager from a Server 2008 R2 Standard Full version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to need to launch the MMC with security credentials that have permission in the domain that the Server 2008 R2 machine is  a member of. Information on running a MMC with with RunAs can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782756(WS.10).aspx).